# How to Intercept errors and change the style of libvlcsharp xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I have correctly implemented **LibVlcSharp** in my **Xamarin.Forms** project.

```
using (var _libVLC = new LibVLC())
            {
                var media = new Media(_libVLC, _link, FromType.FromLocation);
                myvideo.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media)
                {
                    Fullscreen = true
                };
                myvideo.MediaPlayer.Play();
            };
```

In my video player I stream video from google drive but sometimes it can happen that the media gives error and this error is shown:

[image]

**Streaming works**, there may be many reasons for the error but that's not what interests me.
I would like to understand how to **intercept this error** and **customize this error label** but I have not found anything in the documentation or online.

I also wanted to know if it was possible to change the style of the buttons, I found this property `myvideo.PlaybackControls` that has many other properties but I do not know if it is correct and how to apply it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is `ShowError method` but no other details

```cs
private void ShowError()
{
    var errorTextBlock = ErrorTextBlock;
    if (errorTextBlock != null)
    {
        errorTextBlock.Text = string.Format(ResourceLoader.GetString("Error"), Manager.Get<StateManager>().MediaResourceLocator);
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, ErrorState, true);
    }
}
```

You can get more log by subscribing to [`LibVLC.Log` event](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/1cdbe2831acb705b76d385004c547db4e810cd70/docs/how_do_I_do_X.md#how-do-i-get-libvlc-logs)

I havent run code but I believe you can intercept errors with `ErrorOccured`  event as below

```cs
var stateManager = Manager.Get<StateManager>();
stateManager.ErrorOccured += (sender, e) => ShowError();
```

That should give you what is causing the issue, if not you should raise an issue on [libvlcsharp github](https://github.com/issues)

Looks like  they have created `PlayBackControls` property bind to PlayBackControls of LibVLCSharp.Uno library PlayBackControls element and the icons are applied through [this XAML](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/5b4895d4160f515517cda9b3332bee37d09b0f7b/LibVLCSharp.Uno/Themes/PlaybackControls.xaml)

```xml
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaybackControls}" />
```

You should be able to change it by binding as far as it matches [PlayBackControls.Android.iOS](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/LibVLCSharp.Uno/PlaybackControls.Android.iOS.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
 <Label Text="{TemplateBinding ErrorMessage}" Style="{TemplateBinding MessageStyle}"
                       IsVisible="{TemplateBinding ErrorMessage, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBoolConverter}}" />
```

From https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/LibVLCSharp.Forms/Shared/Themes/Generic.xaml. This is the base style provided by LibVLCSharp that you want to modify.

You can override the style by following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/inheritance

In XAML, that could be

```
<Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource MessageStyle}">
   <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Teal" />
</Style>
```

I created a ticket to add more docs about this https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/309

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all items and add your controls.

```xml
<vlc:MediaPlayerElement x:Name="VideoView"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                            EnableRendererDiscovery="False"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">

        <vlc:MediaPlayerElement.PlaybackControls>
            <vlc:PlaybackControls IsVisible="true"
                                  IsAspectRatioButtonVisible="True"
                                  ShowAndHideAutomatically="True"
                                  IsRewindButtonVisible="True"
                                  IsCastButtonVisible="True"
                                  IsLockButtonVisible="True"
                                  IsSeekBarVisible="True"
                                  IsSeekButtonVisible="True"
                                  IsSeekEnabled="True"
                                  IsTracksButtonVisible="True">

                <vlc:PlaybackControls.RemainingTimeLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter  Property="IsVisible"
                                 Value="false" />
                    </Style>
                </vlc:PlaybackControls.RemainingTimeLabelStyle>

                <vlc:PlaybackControls.MessageStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter  Property="IsVisible"
                                 Value="false" />
                        <Setter  Property="TextColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                      
                        
                        <Setter Property="Text"
                                Value="0" />
                    </Style>
                </vlc:PlaybackControls.MessageStyle>


                <vlc:PlaybackControls.ElapsedTimeLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter  Property="IsVisible"
                                 Value="false" />
                    </Style>
                </vlc:PlaybackControls.ElapsedTimeLabelStyle>
            </vlc:PlaybackControls>
        </vlc:MediaPlayerElement.PlaybackControls>
    </vlc:MediaPlayerElement>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).